# Combining String Plus Variable Within Attribute In LWC Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to combine a string plus a variable in an attribute in a component?

I'd like to concatenate "website.com?" with `recordId` to render https://website.com? 0018c0000289v0pAAA

So ultimately the value attribute would render to value="website.com?0018c0000289v0pAAA" at runtime.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Generate Facility Registration Link">
        <lightning-button label="Show Text" title="Get Link" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        <div if:true={showText}>
            <p><lightning-formatted-url value="website.com?{recordId}" tooltip="Access the facility registration page" target="_blank"></lightning-formatted-url></p>
            <p>{recordId}</p>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';

export default class GenerateRegistrationLink extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    showText = false;

    handleClick(event){
        this.showText = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You need to calculate the value in the controller, and expose it directly to the template.

In this case, you can use a getter method.

```
value={websiteUrl}
```

...

```
get websiteUrl() {
  return `website.com?${this.recordId}`
}
```

Or you can calculate it manually:

```
websiteUrl
_recordId
@api set recordId(value) {
  this.websiteUrl = `website.com?${value}`
  this._recordId = value
}
get recordId() {
  return this._recordId
}
```

For your use case, I'd recommend just a simple getter method, but either are a viable option.

Comment: yup, that makes sense. Definitely overthought that one.